# How to make async task run on background?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, console-application

I have this code with TaskCompletionSource. I need to use in my console app. But the point is that it should be finished in background. If I now use `await queries.MarkRandomTaskWithDelay(1000)` it waits 1000 ms and then I can continue working with app. But I need to continue working immediately and only then to receive result. How can I do it?

```
public static class queries
{
    public static TaskCompletionSource<int> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    public static Task<int> MarkRandomTaskWithDelay(int interval)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(interval)
        {
            AutoReset = false
        };

        timer.Elapsed += Marking;

        timer.Start();
        return completionSource.Task;
    }

    private async static void Marking(object o, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await SomeWork();

            Console.WriteLine($"\nTask status with ID {task.Id} was changed to 'finished' in background.\n");
            completionSource.SetResult(task.Id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            completionSource.SetException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `SomeWork`? Is it asynchronous?

Comment: @JohnWu it's a couple of awaited async requests and getting random number.

Comment: If it contains awaited async requests, shouldn't you be calling it with await, e.g. `await SomeWork();` ?

Comment: @JohnWu my mistake. It's also awaited. But it still doesn't work

Comment: I can't find the `MarkRandomTaskWithDelay` method in the code you posted.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias edited it

Comment: You said that you want to continue working immediately after invoking the `MarkRandomTaskWithDelay`, before it is completed, but you also want to use later the final result. Couldn't you store the `Task` created by the `MarkRandomTaskWithDelay` in a variable, and `await` it later to get the result?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias No, it's my task. If waiting for result, my console interface will be frozen and I need to continue working with it and get the result when it's done

Comment: So I assume that you can continue working without the result. What are you going to do with the result? It seems that it may not be essential, since your application does not depend on it.

Comment: Please post the code that calls `MarkRandomTaskWithDelay`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias i print it to console in my event handler `Marking`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias `await queries.MarkRandomTaskWithDelay(1000);` This code calls method in my Main

Comment: Does removing the `await` before the `queries.MarkRandomTaskWithDelay(1000);` solve the problem?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, removing `await` helps, but it's one of the requirements of my task to call it with await

Comment: How about this: `Task.Run(async () => await queries.MarkRandomTaskWithDelay(1000));`? This allows to both await and not await it at the same time.

Comment: it's the same as removing `await` but just an extra Task. I thought that issue is somewhere in `TaskCompletionSource` or event handler

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. It seems like you are trying to find a solution to an unsolvable problem with contradicting requirements.

Comment: Still thank you. If I don't find solution I'm planning to use `parallel.Invoke()`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `await` until you actually need the result.

```
//Start the task but don't wait for it to finish
Task<int> task = queries.MarkRandomTaskWithDelay(1000);

//Do whatever work we can do without knowing the result
DoOtherWork();
 
//Now we need the result, so we await the original task
int result = await task;
UseTheResult(result);
```